# Jenkins Grovvy pipeline : setting build options

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkins job using grovvy pipeline scripts (I am new at this). I am stuck at a place where I want to trigger another Job with some build options set.

[image: Jenkins Job Snippet]

Basically, without grovvy pipeline script, I can do above (as shown in picture) using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) and it provides me useful variables like ${TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMER_} (as shown in the picture, I am triggering job named Another-Job) and I can also set options like "Block until the triggered projects to finish their builds" and the options below them (as shown in the picture)

I, actually, don't know how to do this using pipeline script. Can someone help me in this or point me to the appropriate documentations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) that does exactly that :

```
build job: 'Another-Job', parameters: [
     [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'operation', value: "${OPERATION}" ],
     [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'beanstalk_application_version', value: "${TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_ANother-Job}-{GIT-COMMIT}" ]]
```

2 things worth noting :

1. The "block until triggered project is finished" is the default option of this build step, and this step also propagate any downstream error by default. You can use `propagate` and `wait` params if you want do deactivate this default behaviour.
2. Environment variables or Groovy-defined variables are all available with the same notation, as they would have been available with your freestyle triggering job. Just make sure you use `double quotes` and not `simple quotes` around your variables, otherwise the variables won't be interpreted and replaced when triggering downstream jobs.

Answer (score 0):

To build a job with default settings simply write:

```
build 'Another-Job'
```

To build a job with parameters:

```
build job: 'Another-Job', parameters: [string(name: 'some-param-name', value: 'some-param-default-value')]
```

In general to write pipeline code I suggest you work closely with the pipeline-syntax documentation provided by any running jenkins at:
http://my-jenkins-url/job/my-job-name/pipeline-syntax/